# Ruby on Rails and Phusion Passenger on Mac with OS "Snow Leopard" problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, deployment, passenger

I'm trying to deploy my application using Ruby on Rails and Phusion Passenger on my Mac with OS "Snow Leopard" v10.6.5. I read lots of guides on the Internet and I got a headache!

**What I did is**:

1 . I installed Passenger as described [here](http://www.modrails.com/install.html).

2 . I edited the '/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf' file adding these code lines:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.2
PassengerRuby /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
```

3 . I restarted apache from  the "System Preferences" Panel

Info: at this time if I go to 'http://localhost/' in the browser, I get the common page index.html from 'User/< my_user_name >/Sites/' folder. It seems all work.

4 . I copied the folder of my RoR application (< my_ror_application_name> folder within app directory, config directory, config.ru file, ...) in 'User/< my_user_name >/Sites/'

5 . I edited the '/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf' file adding these code lines:

```
   < VirtualHost *:80 >

      ServerName < my_ror_application_name> .com
      DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/< my_ror_application_name>/public   

   < / VirtualHost >
```

6 . I restarted apache from  the "System Preferences" Panel

Now if I go to 'http://localhost/' in the browser, I get the "Impossible to find localhost" alert.

I think there is something wrong with the Document root with the step 5 or, maybe, in the public folder of my application...

In my RoR application, the public directory have these files and directories:

- 404.html
- 422.html
- 500.html
- robot.txt
- images directory
- javascripts directory
- stylesheets directory

**What's wrong?!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look to [passenger pane](https://github.com/alloy/passengerpane). For me it works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks! Now all is more simple!